# android delete data from mysql using listview multiple selection and volley

Tags: php, android, listview, android-volley

now I'm working on my project and i have a problems how to delete data from mysql using listview multiple selection and volley. I don't have any description. I'm new in android, can anyone help me??.

Comment: Send listview selected item id in volley request then delete it from php using delete query for delete data from Database.

Comment: Refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_delete_php.htm) for php side.  and also Refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) for both side.

Comment: For DELETE with Volley, try [my sample at GitHub](https://github.com/ngocchung/DeleteRequest)

Comment: Good example @BNK ..but I think need array for delete Multiple data .Right?

Comment: @bdevloper ah yes, I just mean a reference for a simple DELETE request with Volley

Comment: ah yes I know, but how can I delete multiple data?? that is my problem :D @bdevloper

Comment: your php side code is done for delete data ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it from php side(means code) but you have to pass array of multiple data's id which you want to delete in request of volley.

Comment: And volley not support of direct arraylist pass in request you can achieve this using add in **JSONArray** in req of **JSONObject** .

Comment: my php can only delete single data @bdevloper

Comment: [multiple delete using php](http://freefeast.info/tutorials-for-beginners/php-tutorials/delete-data-from-mysql-using-php-delete-multiple-data-from-mysql-using-php/)